# tinyMCE formatter - apply format globally

Tags: jquery, editor, tinymce

How can I apply custom format globally and not just to the selected node?

This is what I am doing but it will only apply to the selected node:

```
var fontSize = 12;

tinyMCE.activeEditor.formatter.apply('fontSize', {
    value : fontSize
});
```

What I want to achieve is: on font-size change, if there is nothing selected on the tinymce editor, apply the font-size to all nodes or the main parent.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Such things are being handler in the Fromatter.js-class of the tinycme editor core.
Unfortunatly you cannot change that behaviour using configuration options.

What you can do is to save your actual selection, select the whole editor content and apply the format to the tinymce editors iframe body element you can get using `ed.getBody()`.
Afterwards you may reset the former selection.